# Clicking edit text in fragment causes toolbar to slide off screen

Tags: android, android-fragments

The layout fits perfectly in my fragment normally, but it is a chatting app with an edit text on the bottom of the fragment. If I click the edit text, the fragment gets pushed up and half the fragment goes off the top of the screen. 
Reading other answers, I know for activities this issue is resolved by adding the adjustResize option in the xml. Tried adding it for the entire app in my case, but that still didn't fix the issue. Anyone else have this problem?

pictures:
[image: fragmentkeyboard]
[image: fragmentnokeyboard]

Comment: Could you pls attach screenshots?

Comment: try that in your edittext view android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" or android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: tried adding it to the edittext, but still same result. Also attached screenshots